# iterate through a map of string object that has mutiple values per key

Tags: java, codenameone

I'm receiving the following JSON object and I'm only interested in the errors.  I can log to the console each key and value.  The issue is for example 'Email' key has 2 x values, how can i create a map or list so every value has its own key and remove the JSON formatting?

```
{
    "errors":
    {
        "Email":["'Email' must not be empty.","'Email' is not a valid email address."],
        "Company":["'Company' must not be empty."],
        "LastName":["'Last Name' must not be empty."],
        "Password":["'Password' must not be empty."],
        "FirstName":["'First Name' must not be empty."],
        "Telephone":["'Telephone' must not be empty."]

    },
        "title":"One or more validation errors occurred.",
        "status":400,
        "traceId":"80005307-0001-5d00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}
```

In codenameone i'm parsing using JSON parser in to a map of string, object:

```
  Map<String,Object> result = new JSONParser().parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(r.getResponseData()), "UTF-8"));
  Map<String,Object> value = (Map<String,Object>) result.get("errors");                                                       


 for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : value.entrySet()) {

      Log.p(entry.getKey());
      Log.p(entry.getValue().toString())            
   }
```

Comment: `Email` doesn't has multiple values. It has a single value which is a list

Comment: Trying to understand your requirement. Are you expecting 2 separate keys in the result map for each email value?

Comment: yes ramu please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `email` field is a *list*, as indicated by the `[]` square brackets.

Since it appears that all the fields of `errors` have lists of strings, you should simple cast to `Map<String, List<String>>`, so you don't have to cast any further.

```
Map<String,Object> result = /*result of parsing JSON input*/;

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
Map<String, List<String>> errors = (Map) result.get("errors");                                                       
for (Entry<String, List<String>> error : errors.entrySet()) {
    String name = error.getKey();
    List<String> messages = entry.getValue();

    Log.p(name);
    for (String message : messages)
        Log.p("  " + message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's your thing, brother, I just changes some names for better readability:

```
    Map<String,Object> errors = (Map<String,Object>) map.get("errors");
    Collection<Object> values = errors.values();

    values.stream().flatMap(x->((ArrayList<String>)x).stream()).forEach(value -> {
      String key = errors.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .filter(tempEntry -> ((ArrayList<String>)tempEntry.getValue()).contains(value))
          .findAny()
          .get()
          .getKey();
      System.out.println(key + value);
    });
```

So ye from that you can create a Collection of entries. Currently we print them, but you can skip ".getKey()" and "System.out" and start adding them to a collection.

Comment: Don't cast to `ArrayList`, cast to `List`. The JSON parser is allowed to use whatever type of list it wants.